# sorting an array of score(int) along with its corresponding name(string)

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I am making a scrabble app and I want to make a top score system. I started making an array where the names of the players and their corresponding scores are saved. I want to sort the array of scores so that they are arranged from highest to lowest and output the scores (in descending order) along with the corresponding names. Please guide me on how to sort the scores and output them along with the corresponding player names. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**here's what I have so far:**

```
public class MainTop extends Activity {

TextView show;
EditText name;
EditText score;
Button ok;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layouttop);

    show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    score = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String [] namearray = new String [4];
        int [] scorearray = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            String playername = name.getText().toString();
            namearray[i] = playername;

            String playerscorestr = score.getText().toString();
            int playerscore = Integer.parseInt(playerscorestr);
            scorearray[i] = playerscore;

            show.setText(namearray[i] + scorearray[i]);

        }
```

Comment: Why dont you make a `Player` class which has members `name` and `score`? Then you can have a `List<Player>` which is easier to sort.

Comment: You'll face the persistence problem soon, so why don't you just start with a database and sorting is trivial

Comment: is there another way instead that i could use but with the same idea as what I am trying to do here? I am finding it difficult to sort the scores and compare the two different arrays.

Comment: @chArm show me the relationship between scores array and name array so that I can help you...How do you separate them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't where do you relate scores and players but If your scores and players are  like this than you can try this

```
        int[] scores={10,50,20,60};
        String[] players={"player1","player2","player3","player4"};
        Hashtable<String, String> playerdetails=new Hashtable<String, String>();
        ArrayList scoreslist=(ArrayList) Arrays.asList(scores);
        for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++)
        {
            playerdetails.put(String.valueOf(scores[i]), players[i]);
        }
        Collections.sort(scoreslist);
        for(int i=0;i<scoreslist.size();i++)
        {
            show.setText(scoreslist.get(i)+"    "+playerdetails.get(scoreslist.get(i)));
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I'll start to make my project work now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It might be best if you create a class which represents a `Player`. It would have properties such as `score`, `name`, etc and then, you would make your `Player` class implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface so that you can specify how will the object be sorted.

Once you have that, you could create a `List` of players and use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort your `Player` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Make player class like this

```
public class LabelModel {

    public ArrayList<LabelModel> labelModels;
    public String labelId, labelName;

    public ArrayList<LabelModel> getLabelModels() {
        return labelModels;
    }

    public void setLabelModels(ArrayList<LabelModel> labelModels) {
        this.labelModels = labelModels;
    }

    public String getLabelId() {
        return labelId;
    }

    public void setLabelId(String labelId) {
        this.labelId = labelId;
    }

    public String getLabelName() {
        return labelName;
    }

    public void setLabelName(String labelName) {
        this.labelName = labelName;
    }

}
```

and set array list like

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        labelModel = new LabelModel();
        JSONObject labeljson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        labelModel.setLabelId("id");
        labelModel.setLabelName("player name");
        labelarray.add(labelModel);
        }
```